# Adding plot arguments to plots created with a pivot table in matplotlib

Tags: python, numpy, pandas, matplotlib, plot

If I call `plt.plot(xvars, yvars)` then I can add additional parameters prior to that as follows:

```
plt.ylim(ymax = 4)
plt.xlim(xmax = 2)
plt.ylabel('ytitle')
plt.xlabel('xtitle', fontsize=30)
plt.title('Title', fontsize=40)
```

I'd like to do the same for a plot created via pivot table:

```
plottable_df = df.pivot(index="index_col", columns="var1", values="var2")
plottable_df.plot(kind="line")
```

How do I make these changes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ordering in the following way solved my problem:

```
plottable_df = df.pivot(index="index_col", columns="var1", values="var2")
plt.gcf()
plottable_df.plot(kind="line")
```

Thanks atomh33ls for the suggestion, I'm adding the correct order of lines as well.

Answer (score 0):

Try putting `plt.gcf()` first. This gets a reference to the current figure.

Comment: That didn't work.  It created a separate plot with the axis names and title instead of adding them to the plot I drew.